# invoice pdf not generate in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cache, permissions

I have install **magento 2.0.7**  in **digital ocean droplet**. When i print any invoice give a error

> "This site can’t be reached".

If i generate pdf from drop down "pdf Invoices" on Invoices listing page give a "The Path 'path' is not writable" error. Also wrong path show in error see below

**The path ".:///var/www/html/magento_test/var/var/www/html/magento_test/var/" is not writable**

is it some permission issue or any other issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. It's permission issue of var/www/html/magento_test/var/ folder. I have simply run command `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento/var/cache` and issue not appear.